# Regex pattern in Java. Fix semicolons

Tags: java, regex

i wrote Regex `.*?(?=;)|(?<=;).*` which have to take values between semicolons. My text: `2014-01-01 00:01:00;;16;4;0;0;1`. Actual it parsing string to this:

`[2014-01-01 00:01:00, , , 16, , 4, , 0, , 0, , 1]`.

It replaces semicolons to spaces, which is unwanted feature of course, how to fix it ?

Comment: are you using `String#split` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do splitting on one or more semi-colons.

```
string.split(";+");
```

or

Match any character but not of `;` one or more times.

```
Pattern.compile("[^;]+");
```